# Rails View Is Returning Whole Hash Instead of Just Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is a quick one:

In my rails view I have:

```
<% h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 } %>
<%= h.each_key { |key| puts key } %>
```

This is returning the following in the view:

> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}

However, according to the ruby api doc (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_key), it should just return the following:

> a 
>   b

Why is the whole hash being listed in the view instead of just the key output? I know that this is probably I stupid question, but I have been stuck on this for awhile.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try <%= h.map { |key,value| key } %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code for correct result:

```
<% { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }.each_key do |key| %>
  <%= key %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

When you write `pusts key` key is wrote to log (and console). When you write `<%= key %>` key is wrote to your page.